# What is ffprobe metadata "programs"?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata, ffprobe

All in the topic: what are "progams" in context of video?

As you may expect, any google lookup containg "programs" yield many irrelevant results... no matter search tricks you can apply.

I tried some general search about video metadata, found a [glossary about digital & multimedia](https://www.leva.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/SWGDE-Glossary.pdf), and also a [search engine about metadata](https://www.metadata2go.com/) but didnt get anything.

In the [ffprobe doc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe-all.html)  it seems to be sort of the container, but what is its use?

thanks for any reply which lift this fog ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPEG Transport Streams (`.ts`) are used to carry television content over satellite or cable systems..etc. A transport stream may contain multiple channels in it. For each channel, there will be a video stream, one or more audio streams, zero or more subtitle streams, and possibly other data streams. All streams associated with a particular channel is organized into a 'program'.